# Emacs show modal shortcut keys

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to show all the shortcut keys that have been defined by a mode, for example dired and slime?

so say I am in dired mode, is there a key that i can press to get a list of commands and a list of shortcut keys that go with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> shows the help for the current buffer's major mode and minor modes.

Most mode help includes a list of keybindings.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something easy from before but just couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> also gives a list of all currently active keybindings.